# how to allow only 1 account login 1 server

Tags: java, database

I have 2 simple java game servers using the same database. I wonder how to allow only 1 account to login to 1 server. Currently, it is possible to login 1 account to 2 servers and that messes up the data.

Comment: Please clarify what type of database you have and what form of login are you using? Passwords? If both servers use the same database, why shouldn't logins be allowed in both? Have you tried storing login session information or a counter to the database?

Comment: you have to lock tables and use some flags on the database server, or if the servers run in same process you can use some boolean variables.